# how to add .install file to the new feature folder?

Tags: 7, features

I have created new feature and needs to add .install file to create new table like create new module way

but the table have not been created

can you advice me with the right way to do or i have to create a new module along with the feature
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you stay out of the files that Features generated, you can add code to the (Features generated) module the way you normally do things.

The problem is that your module is already installed when you're adding the schema via .install. You'll need to implement [hook_update_N](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7) and add the tables using [db_create_table](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_create_table/7). Run `update.php` or `drush updatedb` and your schema should be created.

Comment: but as u say if i put hook_schema inside origin files does it work ? i did but nothing changed

Comment: You need to put hook_schema in the .install file _and_ implement hook_update_n in combination with db_create_table. Hook_schema is for people installing the module (feature) from scratch, the update for people who have the module already installed. See [https://drupal.org/node/150215](https://drupal.org/node/150215) for more details